# Удалить модель gensim

Tags: python, gensim

Из библиотеки gensim можно загружать эмбединги слов:

```
import gensim.downloader as api

model = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')
```

Есть ли способ удалить эти модели?

Comment: Проще всего наверное поискать по имени файла и просто удалить файл )

Comment: я же не знаю, куда это ставится

Comment: Ну так я и говорю - поискать по диску. Чем именно - зависит от системы.

Comment: а как искать по диску? посоветуйте поисковик